# iPhone 11 - Dictation commands for navigation and editing?

Tags: iphone, voice-dictation

Due to an injury in my shoulder, I'm relying more and more on iPhone dictation to write emails and WhatsApp messages. It works like a charm when my words are understood correctly; however, I have been unable to find commands to navigate, corrected misspelled/misunderstood words, and edit partially written messages.

Are there commands for this? Or is there a way to program them? I don't need very specialized functions. Just navigation and editing.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips that should help...

For navigation, you should be able to "Hey Siri, navigate to 123 Main St" and maps will open and navigation will start.

Correcting misspelled words, if you double tap on a word, it will get highlighted.  There should then be a mic icon on the keyboard at the bottom.  Clicking on that icon will allow you to say the word again, or replace it with something else, etc.

Above all assuming of course you have some control even with the bad shoulder!

Comment: I think with "navigation", OP meant moving the cursor/selection. The whole point seems to be to correct mistakes/mispellings using only their voice, without touching the screen (so no double tapping).